# Different IPs are for different apps

Tags: django, python-3.x

At first, I am learning Python and Django only... So I'm a noobie yet.
I need to build a microservice architecture to I could run each my service on a separate server machine. In the Django I need to create an environment, project and apps. So, can I run these apps after on different servers? If no, how can I make it with Django? Do I need to create a separate project for each service?
**P.S.** If my question is stupid, pls, explain where am I wrong. I am from Java Spring world where I was need to create just new app for each service.

Comment: Django is monolithic, it's not intended for micro services. Use Flask, use Tornado or Go. Not the use case for Django to build a micro service architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much... I will read about it then. Just I found two articles how to build microservices with Django but it looked very ugly solution, so decided to ask to know clearly if it supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either approach will work.

If it makes sense for your services to share the same code base, you can create a single project and use separate apps for each service and separate settings files for each deployment. The settings file would activate the desired app by listing it in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and would include settings specific to that service.

Or, if you don't need the services to be coupled in that way, you could certainly make each one its own project.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I am thinking now to use Django for a client only

Comment: Scaling Django in microservice way will make things odd, so separating the contexts in a more lightweight way - say using Flask (Docker for container) or Tornado (Docker for container) makes more sense. The DjangoAdmin can still be used, but then you'll need to figure out whether touse SQLAlchemy or Peewe or any other way to handle models.